# From two date time value - assign the given date time value to the nearest/left most value of date time

Tags: python-3.x

```
array = (['2017 SEP 9 06:13:50', '2017 SEP 9 10:39:54', '2017 SEP 9 15:05:58', '2017 SEP 9 19:31:59', '2017 SEP 9 23:58:04', '2017 SEP 10 04:24:07', '2017 SEP 10 08:50:09', '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12','2017 SEP 10 17:42:16'], dtype=object) and each elemnt associated with the index value.
```

```
target1 = 2017 SEP 10 10:15:27
target2 = 2017 SEP 10 10:20:22, ...
```

Finding the nearest value for the `'target1'`,`'target2'`,... is giving me `'2017 SEP 10 13:16:12'` and related `'index'` value.
But, I need to assign the `'target1,2...n'` value with the same index value of `'2017 SEP 10 08:50:09'`, until it reaches the next value `(2017 SEP 10 13:16:12)`.

example:

a=`'2017 SEP 10 08:50:09'`
b= `'2017 SEP 10 13:16:12'`

target=`'2017 SEP 10 12:10:15'` and it is close to the b. but, I need any value between `08:50:09` to `13:16:12` should give `08:50:09` (index value).
if `13:16:13` it should start giving b index value.

I tried code,

```py
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]
```

**Credit goes to the author (I got it from Stack overflow forum).**

I tried all possible ways of correcting this code to fit my result. but, no result.

Questions like: finding the nearest value between array - not serving my purpose.

Any suggestions.

Thank You

Comment: No, I have rewritten my question. please, let me know you are able to follow.

Comment: You want something like [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AlienatedUntriedPayware#main.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is following almost Sebastien D code. To fit my result expectations, I just added the if loop (which gives me a previous index of date for given target1,2,..n rather than the nearest date of an index )

```
import dateparser

array = ['2017 SEP 9 06:13:50', '2017 SEP 9 10:39:54', '2017 SEP 9 15:05:58', '2017 SEP 9 19:31:59', '2017 SEP 9 23:58:04', '2017 SEP 10 04:24:07', '2017 SEP 10 08:50:09', '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12','2017 SEP 10 17:42:16']
target1 = "2017 SEP 10 10:15:27"
target2 = "2017 SEP 10 10:20:22"
def find_closest_date(target,array):
    #convert the target value in datetime
    target = dateparser.parse(target)
    #convert the array in an array of datetimes
    array_dt = [dateparser.parse(x) for x in array]
    #calculate time differences between target and values in list
    deltas = [np.abs(target-x) for x in array_dt]

    #grab the index of the minimum delta
    index_of_closest = deltas.index(min(deltas))
   
    if dateparser.parse(array[index_of_closest]) > target :
       return array[index_of_closest - 1]
    else:
       return array[index_of_closest]

print(target1, '- closest value in list :',find_closest_date(target1,array))
print(target2, '- closest value in list :',find_closest_date(target2,array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to handle your values as `datetime` to allow comparisons. You can easily do that with the `dateparser` library:

```
import dateparser

array = ['2017 SEP 9 06:13:50', '2017 SEP 9 10:39:54', '2017 SEP 9 15:05:58', '2017 SEP 9 19:31:59', '2017 SEP 9 23:58:04', '2017 SEP 10 04:24:07', '2017 SEP 10 08:50:09', '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12','2017 SEP 10 17:42:16']
target1 = "2017 SEP 10 10:15:27"
target2 = "2017 SEP 10 10:20:22"
def find_closest_date(target,array):
    #convert the target value in datetime
    target = dateparser.parse(target)
    #convert the array in an array of datetimes
    array_dt = [dateparser.parse(x) for x in array]
    #calculate time differences between target and values in list
    deltas = [np.abs(target-x) for x in array_dt]
    #grab the index of the minimum delta
    index_of_closest = deltas.index(min(deltas))

    return array[index_of_closest]

print(target1, '- closest value in list :',find_closest_date(target1,array))
print(target2, '- closest value in list :',find_closest_date(target2,array))
```

**Output**

```
2017 SEP 10 10:15:27 - closest value in list : 2017 SEP 10 08:50:09
2017 SEP 10 10:20:22 - closest value in list : 2017 SEP 10 08:50:09
```

Comment: I have found: when I am giving target = '2017 Sep 10 15:30:11' . it is supposed to give me  '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12'  but it is giving next value ('2017 SEP 10 17:42:16'). why it is taking? any suggestion

Comment: why should it give you  '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12' ? It's not the closest date :)

Comment: any value between '2017 SEP 10 13:16:12' and '2017 SEP 10 17:42:16'. Should take the previous values (It is required for my calculation ). ex:  '2017 Sep 10 15:30:11'  falls between these two values and it should be assigned to the previous value. Thank You